# Need help working with bidimensional arrays of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sdl

I am working on a tetris game in C and I am trying to store the blocks which have fallen in a bidimensional array to then draw them on the screen and work with them afterwards. I am trying to make a function to add the blocks into the array by reference. Specifically I wanna know how can I store the blocks in the array so that I can use draw(Block* block, SDL_Renderer* renderer) for instance on them afterwards. I created a matrix of pointers and I'm trying to add the blocks from the gameBlock into it after it fell on the ground. Now after the block falls, it just stays there, even though I call initGameBlock on it. I don't have a good idea on what's going on, please help. The part where I am adding the blocks and reinitializing the "activeBlock" is in updateGameBlock. How can I make this matrix work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

//Initialize the constants for the screen width, height and block width
const int width = 600;
const int height = 800;
const int bwidth = 40;

//Enum for storing the types of blocks
typedef enum {BLOCK, LINE, CHAIR, TABLE, BED} Type; 

//This variable is used in the update function in order to make timing work
float prevTicks = 0;

//Function that returns ceiling of a number
int mceil(double num){
    return (int)num + 1;
}

//Struct ofr position/velocity
typedef struct{
    float x, y;
} Vector2;

//Function to keep a value between some constrains
void limit(int* value, int min, int max){
    if(*value > max){
        *value = max;
    }
    if(*value < min){
        *value = min;
    }
}

//The blocks in the game
typedef struct Block{
    Vector2 position;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect rect;
} Block;

//"Consturctor" for the block
void initBlock(Block* block, float x, float y, SDL_Texture* texture){
    block->position.x = x;
    block->position.y = y;
    block->rect.x = (int) x - bwidth / 2;
    block->rect.y = (int) y - bwidth / 2;
    block->rect.w = bwidth;
    block->rect.h = bwidth;
    block->texture = texture;
}

//The gameblock consisting of 4 blocks
typedef struct GameBlock{
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 velocity;
    int falling;
    Type type;
    Block blocks[4];
    SDL_Texture* texture;
} GameBlock;

//"Constructor" for the falling blocks
void initGameBlock(GameBlock* gameBlock, float x, float y, float xvel, float yvel, Type type, SDL_Texture* texture){
    gameBlock->falling = 1; //Variable which tells whether the block is falling
    gameBlock->position.x = x;  
    gameBlock->position.y = y;
    gameBlock->velocity.x = xvel;   
    gameBlock->velocity.y = yvel;
    gameBlock->type = type;
    gameBlock->texture = texture;
    switch(gameBlock->type){
        //Depending on the type of the gameBlock, arranges the blocks in a certain way
        case BLOCK: {
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[0]), gameBlock->position.x - bwidth / 2, gameBlock->position.y - bwidth/2, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[1]), gameBlock->position.x + bwidth / 2, gameBlock->position.y - bwidth/2, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[2]), gameBlock->position.x + bwidth / 2, gameBlock->position.y + bwidth/2, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[3]), gameBlock->position.x - bwidth / 2, gameBlock->position.y + bwidth/2, texture);
            break;
        }
        case LINE: {
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[0]), gameBlock->position.x - bwidth / 2 - bwidth, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[1]), gameBlock->position.x + bwidth / 2 + bwidth, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[2]), gameBlock->position.x + bwidth / 2, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[3]), gameBlock->position.x - bwidth / 2, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            break;
        }
        case CHAIR: {
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[0]), gameBlock->position.x, gameBlock->position.y - bwidth, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[1]), gameBlock->position.x + bwidth, gameBlock->position.y - bwidth, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[2]), gameBlock->position.x - bwidth, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[3]), gameBlock->position.x, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            break;
        }
        case TABLE: {
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[0]), gameBlock->position.x, gameBlock->position.y - bwidth, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[1]), gameBlock->position.x + bwidth, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[2]), gameBlock->position.x - bwidth, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[3]), gameBlock->position.x, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            break;
        }
        case BED: {
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[0]), gameBlock->position.x, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[1]), gameBlock->position.x + bwidth, gameBlock->position.y - bwidth, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[2]), gameBlock->position.x - bwidth, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            initBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[3]), gameBlock->position.x + bwidth, gameBlock->position.y, texture);
            break;
        }
    }   
}

//The matrix containing blocks on the ground
Block* blocks[20][15] = {NULL};

//Function to add a block in this matrix
void addBlock(Block* block, Block* blocks[][15]){
    int col = (int) (block->position.x / bwidth);
    int row = (int) (block->position.y / bwidth);
    blocks[row][col] = block;
}

//Function to add the blocks from a gameBlock in the matrix
void addBlocks(GameBlock* gameBlock){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        addBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[i]), blocks);
    }
}

//The logic for the gameBlock
void updateGameBlock(GameBlock** gameBlock){
    //If the gameObject is already on the ground do this:
    if((*gameBlock)->position.y > height - bwidth && (*gameBlock)->falling == 1){
        //Tell that it's not falling
        (*gameBlock)->falling = 0;
        //Add the blocks from the gameBlock into the matrix
        addBlocks(*gameBlock);
        //Reset the pointer and create a new gameBlock at the top
        *gameBlock = NULL;
        *gameBlock = (GameBlock*) malloc(sizeof(GameBlock));
        initGameBlock(*gameBlock, width / 2, bwidth / 2, 1.f, 1.f, BED, (*gameBlock)->texture);
    }
    //If the game object is still in the air
    if((*gameBlock)->falling == 1){
        //This makes it so that the object falls in steps
        if(SDL_GetTicks() - prevTicks >= 100){      
            (*gameBlock)->position.y += (*gameBlock)->velocity.y*bwidth/2;
        }
        //Update the position of the blocks in the gameBlock(all at the same time)
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            (*gameBlock)->blocks[i].rect.x += (*gameBlock)->velocity.x*bwidth;
            (*gameBlock)->blocks[i].position.x += (*gameBlock)->velocity.x*bwidth;
            if(SDL_GetTicks() - prevTicks >= 100){      
                (*gameBlock)->blocks[i].rect.y += (*gameBlock)->velocity.y*bwidth/2;
                (*gameBlock)->blocks[i].position.y += (*gameBlock)->velocity.y*bwidth/2;
                if(i == 3)
                    prevTicks = SDL_GetTicks();
            }
        }
    }
}

//Function for displaying the block on the screen
void drawBlock(Block* block, SDL_Renderer* renderer){
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, block->texture, NULL, &(block->rect));
}

//Function for displaying the whole gameBlock on the screen
void drawGameBlock(GameBlock* gameBlock, SDL_Renderer* renderer){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        drawBlock(&(gameBlock->blocks[i]), renderer);
    }
}

int main(){

    //Initialize SDL, create a window and a renderer
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Tetris", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, 0);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 34, 134, 134, 255);
    int running = 1;    

    GameBlock testBlock;
    SDL_Surface* testSurface = IMG_Load("./res/blueCube.png");
    SDL_Texture* testTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, testSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(testSurface);
    testSurface == NULL;
    GameBlock* activeBlock = &testBlock;


    initGameBlock(&testBlock, width / 2, bwidth / 2, 1.f, 1.f, BED, testTexture);

    SDL_Event e;
    //These variables are for controlling the fps
    float df = 0.f;
    float past = SDL_GetTicks();
    float fps;
    float now;
    float dt;
    while(running){
        //Reset the x velocity of the block
        testBlock.velocity.x = 0.f;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
            switch(e.type){
                case SDL_QUIT: running = 0;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    switch(e.key.keysym.scancode){
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT:
                            activeBlock->velocity.x += -1;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT:
                            activeBlock->velocity.x += 1;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE:
                            running = 0;
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
        //Clear the screen and draw the testBlock
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        drawGameBlock(activeBlock, renderer);
        //Draw the blocks from the matrix
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++){
                if(blocks[i][j] != NULL){
                    drawBlock(blocks[i][j], renderer);
                    printf("x: %d y: %d\n", (int) blocks[i][j]->position.x, (int) blocks[i][j]->position.y);
                }
            }
        }
        updateGameBlock(&activeBlock);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        //Limit the fps
        now = SDL_GetTicks();
        df++;
        dt = (now - past)/1000;
        fps = df / dt;
        if(fps > 60){
            SDL_Delay(mceil((1.f / 30.f - dt / df)*1000));
        }
        if(SDL_GetTicks() % 1000 == 0)
            printf("fps = %d\n", (int) fps);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;

}
```

To compile I use:

gcc -o tetris tetris.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2) -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Your code happily mixes 2D arrays (resp. pointers to array), `**` and 2D arrays of pointers, which are all different datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Your code is quite hard to read and understand (no comments, I can't run it to see what's going on, poor indentation in some places). My answer is more like a short review and some tips from what I could get after a few minutes of starring at the code. If you edit the code/add more details I'll edit my answer accordingly.

When coding applications one of the things to have in mind is to separate the business logic from the visual logic. This helps quite a lot in visualizing what happens, since the code for the interface tends to be quite verbose and if you mix it with logic code, it soon starts to be a mess to debug. Also, you could replace the code for the interface with a thin interface (text only) for debugging the logic part.

Another thing to consider are data inconsistencies. They occur when you store the same data in 2 places and you modify just one of them. You have a data inconsistency in the fact that you put the block in a matrix, but each block knows its location. You don't even need to store the location inside the block structure, you can simply place it in the matrix.

This being said, you need to improve your code's modularity. There should be a function that takes a matrix of blocks and prints it, and that should be the only point of connection to the view library. In the business logic you should only care about the game blocks. After you process them, you simply place their blocks in the matrix and draw the matrix. You will probably meet some difficulties along the way (mostly regarding collisions), but start with this mindset.

Comment: I will try to clean up the code today and provide a well-commented code, also I will try adding the whole code so it can be run. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I should have used an array of gameBlocks instead of an array of pointers. This way I can actually copy the blocks from the gameBlock in the array instead of copying pointers, which resulted in me refferencing the blocks on from the gameBlock and telling them to stay on the floor, which was a problem because I used the same gameBlock in my game, I was not creating another one, rather just reinitializing the old one, so the program was conflicting and the blocks just stayed on the floor.